# Any PEG parser capable to handle left recursion?

Tags: parsing, language-agnostic, grammar, peg

Well, I know it's possible to rewrite the grammar to eliminate left recursion. But this is a very boring process, and sometimes it's very nontrivial to keep correct associativity. Is there any parser capable to handle properly grammars with left recursion?

Comment: AFAIK, by definition, a PEG can't cope with left recursion.

Comment: http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1328424

Comment: @SK-logic, but can Packrat-parsers be called PEG's? (a genuine quiestion, not being a smart-@ss :))

Comment: Well, Packrat is just a one of many ways of parsing PEGs. There is no defined operational semantics for PEG, so it's ok to call Packrat a decent implementation of it.